# jquery datepicker onselect simple function

Tags: jquery, function, datepicker, window.open, onselect

The jquery datepicker plugin works, but I'd like to have onSelect triggering a function which opens a page in a new tab.

The jquery datepicker plugin works, but I'd like to have onSelect triggering a function which opens a page in a new tab.

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: highlightDays,

//works perfectly fine

onSelect: function(dates) { window.open('/en/calendar/' + dates, '_self'); },
});

var dates = [new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 28), new Date(2011, 5 - 1, 10),];

//does not work

onSelect: function(links) { window.open('/en/trip/' + links, '_self'); },

var links = [new Link('link1'), new Link('link2'),];
```

---

the js:

```
$( "#toggleDP" ).click(function() { $("#dp ").datepicker('show'); });

$("#dp").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showOn: 'button',
showButtonPanel: true,
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonImage: "0.gif",
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
onSelect: function(dates) { window.open('/en/calendar/' + dates, '_self'); },
});


var links =[new Link('test'), new Link('test1'), ];
var dates = [new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 28), new Date(2011, 5 - 1, 10), ];
var txt = ['test','test1',];

function highlightDays(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
if (dates[i]-date==0) {
return [true, 'markedDay', txt[i],];
}
}
return [false, ''];
}
```

if i were to set onSelect to function(links) { window.open('/en/trips/' + links, '_self'); }, then for some unknown reasons, it opens an URL with the corresponding DATE not with the corresponding link.

Comment: Can you show us some proper source code, not random line fragments? As of now, you've got it all over the place and please be more specific about what doesn't work and what you want to achieve.

Comment: datepicker works = it opens when called and highlights the days defined in var dates.
If i click on a highlighted date, it should open up a new URL with the date i just clicked on = works.
If I change the OnSelect function to use var links instead of dates, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the onSelect handler syntax:

```
function(dateText, inst)
```

And explanation from the docs:

> The function receives the selected
>   date as text and the datepicker
>   instance as parameters.

So when you say:

```
   onSelect: function(links) { window.open('/en/trips/' + links, '_self'); }
```

So passing as a parameter ***links*** is not actually the array you think it is but inside the handler the context is changed. i.e. ***links*** refers to the selected date as mentioned above.